# Memory copying: ARM STM vs. ARM NEON

Tags: c, memory, arm, neon, cortex-a8

I need to copy large amounts of memory (on the order of 47k) (example, from a USB buffer to a more permanent buffer).

This is using an ARM Cortex A8.

*(The ARM has the NEON code.)*

The ARM NEON instruction can copy 4 32-bit elements at a time (per instruction).
The ARM LDM and STM instructions can load and store (copy) more than 4 registers at a time (per instruction).

### Questions:

1. Which is more efficient for copying large amounts (e.g. 47k) of memory, the ARM NEON instruction or the ARM LDM and STM instructions? (I don't have benchmarking tools available; this is on an embedded system).
2. What is the advantage of the ARM NEON instructions for copying memory?
3. The project is primarily C language, but also has some assembly language.
   Is there a method to suggest to the compiler to use ARM NEON or the LDM/STM instructions, without optimizations? (We are launching code without optimizations so there are no differences when the product is returned.  There is a possibility that optimization can be responsible for issues in the product.)

**Tools:**
ARM Cortex A8 processor
IAR Electronic Workbench IDE & Compiler.
Development on Windows 10 PC, to remote embedded ARM processor (via JTAG).

Comment: Can you try both and find out?

Comment: Our embedded system has Test Points, but I don't have access to them nor to an o'scope or a logic analyzer, so no, I can't do performance analysis.

Comment: All you would have to do is copy some buffer to some other buffer, maybe ten thousand times, and beep or flash an LED when done

Comment: Which is more efficient? - In fact, neither. Trust your `libc`: `memcpy` will do as fast as the controller can. That said, DMA will be faster.

Comment: @user58697 Do you even know how `memcpy` works?

Comment: @user58697:  I have written many custom `memcpy` for embedded systems.  If you step through `memcpy()` in assembly language, there is a lot of "bloat" because `memcpy` is designed for the general use case.  The `memcpy()` function can be made a lot more efficient when specializing for a specific platform and specific use case.  BTW, DMA is only faster if and only if it exists and is available.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @user58697 It's about fact, not about "agree to disagree" Stop spreading wrong and misleading information.

Comment: DMA is **NOT** faster.  It relieves the CPU to do other computations.  The DMA engine will share the bus with other masters and arbitration will occur on the bus matrix.  A core bursting is often given higher priority.  But an important point is that everything depends on the memory type.  For the most part, the code won't matter as much as the source and destination memory properties, if your system is configured sanely and you have a modern core (tag is cortex-a8; 47K is large?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neon has the advantage of unaligned load and store, but it consumes more power.

And since you are copying form the USB buffer to a permant one where you have full control over alignment and size, it would be better without neon, because memory speed is the same.

The standard `memcpy` most probably already utilizes neon (it depends on the BSP), hence I'd write a mini version utilizing `ldrd` and `strd` which is slightly faster than `ldm` and `stm`.

```
.balign 64
    push    {r4-r11}
    sub     r1, r1, #8
    sub     r0, r0, #8
    b       1f
    
.balign 64
1:
    ldrd    r4, r5, [r1, #8]
    ldrd    r6, r7, [r1, #16]
    ldrd    r8, r9, [r1, #24]
    ldrd    r10, r11, [r1, #32]!
    subs    r2, r2, #32
    
    strd    r4, r5, [r0, #8]
    strd    r6, r7, [r0, #16]
    strd    r8, r9, [r0, #24]
    strd    r10, r11, [r0, #32]!
    bgt     1b

.balign 16
    pop     {r4-r11}
    bx      lr
```

I think you have no problem making the buffer size a multiple of 32, and both buffers aligned to 64 bytes(cache line length) or even better, 4096 bytes (page size).

Comment: Wow! This explains why the compiler would always generate `ldr/str` instructions instead of using `ldm/stm`.  Thanks.